# Flat roof, where electric mains enter via conduit, leaks in heavy rain - does a cover for this exist?

Tags: electrical, waterproofing, conduit, roofing

I have a section of the roof on my house that is flat, and across the roof runs a conduit that carries electrical from the main panel to subpanel. In very heavy rain, water enters through a square box that the conduit enters, and subsequently the mains wire runs from into the sub panel. I have seen very small amounts of water leak from the subpanel, which is concerning.

How should the conduit that runs along the roof enter the house? Is there a specific cover that should be used? How can I protect this from ever leaking again?

Comment: What gland is used to allow the conduit entry into the box?

Comment: Can you provide pics of the roof penetrations and where the conduit enters the panels.

Comment: Please [edit] to add pictures.

Comment: There should be a weather head at the entrance so the wires come in and a drip loop won’t allow water to run down the wires.